# C#: How do I add all values in the column of an array into one box. XNA 3D

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to simulate how gravity acts on objects in space using 3D xna programming (for a school project). I am calculating the direction and velocities of each of the objects in relation to each other object and turning this into an array of movements. I am then trying to sum up all the movement of each object into one Vector3 and storing this in a one dimensional array. I am able to add up all the movements apart from the last index value in the array.
This is my Gravitation class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace GravitySimulator
{
class Gravitation
{
    static Random Random = new Random();
    public Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[3], summovement = new Vector3[3];
    public float[,] distance = new float[3, 3], force = new float[4, 4], acceleration = new float[3, 3], velocity = new float[3, 3];
    public Vector3[,] dir = new Vector3[3, 3], movement = new Vector3[3, 3];
    public double G, mass;

    public void GenerateVectors()
    {
        for (int vectors = 0; vectors < positions.Length; vectors++)
        {
            positions[vectors] = new Vector3(Random.Next(-7, 7), Random.Next(-12, 12), Random.Next(-5, 5));
        }
    }

    public void CalculateDistance()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < positions.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                distance[j, i] = Vector3.Distance(positions[j], positions[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CalculateForce()
    {
        G = 6.67 * Math.Pow(10, -11);
        mass = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < positions.Length; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < positions.Length; l++)
            {
                force[k, l] = (float)((G * mass * mass) / Math.Pow(distance[k, l], 2));
            }
        }

    }

    public void CalulateAcceleration()
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < positions.Length; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < positions.Length; n++)
            {
                acceleration[m, n] = (float)(force[m, n] / mass);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SummariseMovement()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < positions.Length; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < positions.Length;b++)
            {
                summovement[a] = movement[a, b];
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I find it rather vague what a 'box' is. Can you try explaining that more? It might also be worth looking into 3-Dimensional arrays.

Comment: Yes sorry, looking back 'box' was probably the wrong word. Im trying to add all the values corresponding to one index row into one value. for example:
summovement[0]
should include the sum of all values with index [0, x]